# How do I temporarily swap out a core package with a locally compiled one?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose I found and want to fix a bug in `ros_comm`.  I've forked and cloned a local copy of `ros_comm` and implemented my fix.  How do I go about testing my fix?  More specifically, how can I temporarily swap out the current `ros_comm` installed in my system with my work in progress `ros_comm` without recompiling the whole ROS stack?

Naively putting `ros_comm` in the same workspace as my package for testing my fix (`test_node`) and building (and sourcing) them together doesn't work as it still uses the system installed `ros_comm`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375692/how-do-i-temporarily-swap-out-a-core-package-with-a-locally-compiled-one?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2021-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-08**:\

> Naively putting `ros_comm` in the same workspace as my package for testing my fix and building (and sourcing) them together doesn't work as it still uses the system installed `ros_comm`.

that is actually supposed to work, so perhaps you should add some more info on what you did exactly.

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-04-08**:
hmm that's strange, my test node in the same workspace is still linking to the system `ros_comm` package, not the custom `ros_comm` package in the local workspace...  It seems to be related to [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/312165/local-package-path-is-not-prioritized-over-installed-package-path/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So afaik, the way to do this would be to place your `ros_comm` fork in an *underlay*.

I'd missed you put everything together in the same workspace.

Your description ("first source, then rebuild") is sort-of the same, but less reproducible and less scalable.

See the docs on [Catkin overlay](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) (and realise what is an *overlay* from one perspective is an underlay from another).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out, in order to get my custom `ros_comm` linked to `test_node`, I need to first build `ros_comm`, then source the workspace, then rebuild `test_node`.

Doing a full rebuild of everything at the same time (with `catkin clean` and `catkin build`) causes `test_node` to be linked to the system `ros_comm` instead of the local one.

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2021-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1